# Viewing all FB comments left on site

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I've been trying to view all FB comments left on my site.

However, when I try to view this: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://soul-sides.com

What I get is this:

```
{
   "http://soul-sides.com": {
      "data": [

      ]
   }
}
```

If I put in the URL of a specific page, I can view the comments for that page but I thought the original graph API would consolidate *all* comments onto a single page.

Up until a month ago, I was able to do that by going here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id=[my FB ID]

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong; the comments do appear on the site itself but I can't get a "consolidated view" as I thought would happen.

Comment: Would adding 'www' make any difference?

Comment: It doesn't. First thing I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

The consolidated/moderated comments view is offered at the same URL that it was supposed to be: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id=[your FB ID]

The problem, with my site, probably happened a  month ago, during a Wordpress theme update that scrubbed tags out of my template. That's why, after Nov. 24th, the moderated page stopped including any posts after that. After looking for answers on this site, I went back and added these two tags back:

```
<head>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="[FB ID #]"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="[FB ID #]"/>
```

Adding these back in fixed the consolidation problem; all comments left since restoring the tags now appear back in the master moderation page.